# Find and Replace a URL using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I've read few articles and posts but I couldn't find out a solution in removing a specific url from a text. I have tried at least 3 different expressions. It's good to know that I'm doing it programmatically (C#).

```
(?<!"")((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&amp;~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])(?!"")

((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)

(?<!\w?="")(((http|https|ftp|news|file)+://)[_.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/_:@=.+?,##%&‌​amp;~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])
```

The example url is below. Note that not all urls will be exactly like that. This is the worst one.

http://api.ning.com/files/*tHd*uipNJAW29nIL5jzWbrYON5NhTKYVXmzollyMEHasDDvnq1454BrFkXFfmzj1gH7Ye3xw03C9ulNTICYAdueKg6vaIeu/PauloSkaf.png

Could someone guide me to the solution?

**UPDATE**

As [hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd) mentioned the best pattern is

```
https?\S+
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: To replace the entire url to an empty string.

Comment: can you post a sample text that includes the url?

Comment: @Gandarez Are there any more urls like this that starts off with `api.ning.com` ?

Comment: @hwnd I can't say yes because I'm invoking a third party service which provides to me this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not fully sure what is your need but if you want to remove that url from a text, you can use a regex like this:

```
https?:.*(?=\s)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pO8qW1/1)**

Check the **substitution section**

[image]

By the way, if you want to remove whatever protocol you could use this one:

```
\w+:\/\/.*?(?=\s)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pO8qW1/4)**

[image]

As **[hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd)** pointed in the comment, you can improve above regex by using:

```
\w+:\/\/\S*
```

Comment: much easier to use `https?://\S+`

Comment: @hwnd you are totally right, I don't know why I always forgot about this. I'll point that in the answer. You rock man, I always learn from you +1

Comment: Take a look at this url http://regex101.com/r/pO8qW1/5 I used your pattern to match my text.

Comment: @Gandarez you should use the last update in my answer from hwnd comment. You can look it here http://regex101.com/r/pO8qW1/6

Comment: @hwnd the tick is for you. Thanks for help me improving the answer.

Comment: @Gandarez thanks for the tick and hwnd for suggesting the improvement